# Changing the Bend Radius While Extrusion Using a Rectangular Profile

Tags: python, scripting, extrude

I have created a rectangular bar using python scripting in Blender by taking a rectangular profile and extruding it along a certain path. The path is defined by a set of coordinates in the 3D space.

I would like to alter the bend radius at edges where it turns and moves into another plane. Presently I am getting a filleted edge on the outside and a sharp edge on the inside. The bend radius needs to be equal to the thickness of the bar which is 8 mm. Can someone provide me the python code for the same?  [image]

Please find the code below-

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

# Define the path
path_coords = [[1587.0001220703125, 56.14859390258789, 123.9989013671875],
 [1583.0001220703125, 56.14859390258789, 123.9989013671875],
 [1579.0001220703125, 56.14859390258789, 123.9989013671875],
 [1575.0001220703125, 56.14859390258789, 123.9989013671875],
 [1575.0001220703125, 60.14859390258789, 123.9989013671875],
 [1575.0001220703125, 64.14859390258789, 123.9989013671875],
 [1575.0001220703125, 68.14859390258789, 123.9989013671875],
 [1575.0001220703125, 72.14859390258789, 123.9989013671875],
 [1575.0001220703125, 76.14859390258789, 123.9989013671875],
 [1575.0001220703125, 80.14859390258789, 123.9989013671875],
 [1575.0001220703125, 84.14859390258789, 123.9989013671875],
 [1575.0001220703125, 88.14859390258789, 123.9989013671875],
 [1575.0001220703125, 92.14859390258789, 123.9989013671875],
 [1575.0001220703125, 96.14859390258789, 123.9989013671875],
 [1575.0001220703125, 100.14859390258789, 123.9989013671875],
 [1575.0001220703125, 100.14859390258789, 127.9989013671875],
 [1571.0001220703125, 100.14859390258789, 127.9989013671875],
 [1567.0001220703125, 100.14859390258789, 127.9989013671875],
 [1563.0001220703125, 100.14859390258789, 127.9989013671875],
 [1559.0001220703125, 100.14859390258789, 127.9989013671875],
 [1559.0001220703125, 104.14859390258789, 127.9989013671875],
 [1559.0001220703125, 108.14859390258789, 127.9989013671875],
 [1559.0001220703125, 112.14859390258789, 127.9989013671875],
 [1559.0001220703125, 116.14859390258789, 127.9989013671875],
 [1559.0001220703125, 120.14859390258789, 127.9989013671875],
 [1559.0001220703125, 124.14859390258789, 127.9989013671875],
 [1559.0001220703125, 128.1485939025879, 127.9989013671875],
 [1559.0001220703125, 132.1485939025879, 127.9989013671875],
 [1559.0001220703125, 136.1485939025879, 127.9989013671875],
 [1559.0001220703125, 140.1485939025879, 127.9989013671875],
 [1559.0001220703125, 144.1485939025879, 127.9989013671875],
 [1559.0001220703125, 148.1485939025879, 127.9989013671875],
 [1559.0001220703125, 152.1485939025879, 127.9989013671875],
 [1559.0001220703125, 156.1485939025879, 127.9989013671875],
 [1559.0001220703125, 160.1485939025879, 127.9989013671875],
 [1559.0001220703125, 164.1485939025879, 127.9989013671875],
 [1559.0001220703125, 168.1485939025879, 127.9989013671875],
 [1559.0001220703125, 172.1485939025879, 127.9989013671875],
 [1559.0001220703125, 176.1485939025879, 127.9989013671875],
 [1559.0001220703125, 176.1485939025879, 131.9989013671875],
 [1559.0001220703125, 176.1485939025879, 135.9989013671875],
 [1559.0001220703125, 176.1485939025879, 139.9989013671875],
 [1559.0001220703125, 176.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1555.0001220703125, 176.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1551.0001220703125, 176.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1547.0001220703125, 176.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1543.0001220703125, 176.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1539.0001220703125, 176.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1535.0001220703125, 176.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1531.0001220703125, 176.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1527.0001220703125, 176.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1523.0001220703125, 176.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 176.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 180.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 184.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 188.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 192.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 196.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 200.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 204.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 208.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 212.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 216.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 220.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 224.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 228.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 232.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 236.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 240.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 244.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 248.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 252.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 256.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 260.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 264.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 268.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 272.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 276.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 280.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 284.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 288.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 292.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 296.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 300.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 304.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 308.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 312.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 316.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875],
 [1519.0001220703125, 320.1485939025879, 143.9989013671875]] 

# Define the rectangle dimensions
rectangle_width = 30
rectangle_height = 6

# Delete all mesh and curve objects
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.ops.object.select_by_type(type='MESH')
bpy.ops.object.select_by_type(type='CURVE')
bpy.ops.object.delete()

# Create the rectangle profile (this will define the cross-section shape of the extrusion)
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(size=1, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0))
rectangle = bpy.context.object
rectangle.scale.x = rectangle_width 
rectangle.scale.y = rectangle_height 

# Convert the rectangle to a curve
bpy.ops.object.convert(target='CURVE')

# Create the path
bpy.ops.curve.primitive_nurbs_path_add()
path = bpy.context.object
path.data.splines[0].points.add(len(path_coords) - 5)
for i, coord in enumerate(path_coords):
    x, y, z = coord
    path.data.splines[0].points[i].co = (x, y, z, 1)

# Set the rectangle as the path's bevel object (this will extrude the rectangle along the path)
path.data.bevel_mode = 'OBJECT'
path.data.bevel_object = rectangle

# Convert the result to a mesh
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
path.select_set(True)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = path
bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH')
```

Comment: Hi Mihir, could you elaborate on what you mean? It think it's reasonable to write a question in the same standard as the answers you would like to get: three sentences of explanation you will probably find confusing, but a Python script and image explanations are more like it: How about you show us an example curve and sketch or manually model the expected output? As far as I understand currently, you want to **fillet** the curve.

Comment: Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is unanswerable and was put on hold for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Risking stating the obvious, only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly you alone know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Describe the issue in detail, add [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) of relevant settings and user interface, with the [edit] button above. Don't post comments or ask a new question, editing will automatically queue it for reopening review.

Comment: Hi, just reviewed again.. could you provide your code, as far as it's gone? Asking for it to be written from scratch is a different thing from getting your own  code reviewed / extended.

Comment: @RobinBetts Could you please check the question now and let me know if you need any clarity?

Comment: Hi @MihirJ Thanks for the edits!  .. the Q looks fine now, to me, (and so re-opened). Providing the code puts potential answerers in the frame.. they can tell what your approach is, and can try making suggestions, adjusting that particular way. (Thanks for your patience, too :) )